# How do you add tags to tag field when saving an entry?

Tags: plugin-development, tags

I'm working on a custom import plugin which needs to import a load of content to fields including categories and tags. Categories is working fine using a comma separated list of category ids:

```
        $entry = new EntryModel();
        $entry->authorId  = $eventObject->author;
        $entry->enabled   = true;
        $entry->postDate   = $eventObject->postDate;
        $entry->getContent()->title = $eventObject->title;
        $entry->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
            'slug' => $eventObject->slug,
            'locationText' => $eventObject->locationText,
            'date' => $eventObject->eventDate,
            'overview' => $eventObject->overview,
            'eventWebsite' => $eventObject->eventWebsite,
            'eventCategories' => $eventObject->categories,
            'location' => $eventObject->location,
            'eventTags' => 1453,
        ));
```

I just can't get tags importing at all, also need to create new tags where a tag doesn't already exist! Testing with the id 1453which is an existing tag id.

Answer (score 3):

Like other relational fields, Tags fields’ values need to be set to an array of the tags’ IDs.

It’s not possible to create tags *during* entry creation; you would just need to create it first using [TagsService::saveTag()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TagsService#saveTag-detail).

```php
$tag = new TagModel();
$tag->groupId = 1;
$tag->getContent()->title = 'My Tag';

$success = craft()->tags->saveTag($tag);

if ($success)
{
    $tagData = array($tag->id);
}
else
{
    $tagData = null;
}

// ...

$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    // ...
    'myTagsField' => $tagData,
));

// ...
```

(Note that I’m setting the field value using [setContentFromPost()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#setContentFromPost-detail) instead of directly on the ContentModel. [This is the recommended way to set your custom field values](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust), although for relational fields it doesn’t really matter either way.)

Comment: Brandon after they are created how do you save tags within "craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry)"? Not sure I understand how setContentFromPost works if it's not a post call?

Comment: @AdamMcCombs `setContentFromPost()` is probably just not the best name for the function. 99% of the time it is called, the data passed in is plucked from $_POST, but that’s not the case here.

Comment: Thanks Brandon. I think that's what's adding to my confusion because it sounds like setContentFromPost and ->getContent() function the same. getContent (instead of say setContent()) reads funny to me but I know I'm being picky about semantics.