# Best way to create tags under new EntryModel?

Tags: tags, import

As best I can tell entries have to be created, tags have to be created, a relationship created and then an update to the original entry. Is this correct or is there a simpler way to do this?

There is a similar question [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/how-do-you-add-tags-to-tag-field-when-saving-an-entry) which address how to create a tags but I feel like how to relate the new tag(s) to the entry could use some elaboration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To relate the tags, all you'd have to do is feed the entry's tag field an array containing tag IDs.

So, after creating (or finding existing) tags, you should end up with an array with one or more tag IDs.

Then, if it's a new entry, you would do:

```
$myTagIds = array(1,2,3,4); // your tag IDs
$entry = new EntryModel();
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    // ...
    'tagFieldHandle' => $myTagIds,
));

craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Comment: Paul - I think your missing a closing parenthesis on line 6 but either way, I can't get setContentFromPost to save my tag array, it saves the entry but the tag field is blank. I can see the array in the craft_entryversions but the tag field (when I go to edit the entry) is blank. I've double checked for valid tag ID's too.

Comment: I always look for answers in Craft's controllers, but I assume you did that already. Don't have time to get into this now. Could it be a locale issue?

Comment: Only one locale here and now I'm looking into the craft controller. I updated my original post to show the snippet I'm using. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I got it. The tag group wasn't specified in the field settings so even though I was specifying the tag IDs I guess it couldn't find them in it's selected group.

Comment: Bugger. It's always the small things that cost most of your time ...