# Plugin: Tags field for front-end Entry Form

Tags: plugin-development, tags

I would like to add tags via a front-end entry form - not like [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/how-do-you-add-tags-to-tag-field-when-saving-an-entry), but as follows:

- Text field in a front-end entry form where user add tags (separated by commas).
- After pressing the save button, the plugin should:
- check for every tag, whether it exists already (and create the tag if not)
- save the tags together with the rest of the entry form [see also [here]](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/how-do-you-add-tags-to-tag-field-when-saving-an-entry)(including the text field with the user defined tags)

Now, I am looking for a developer (I am willing to pay for it).

Comment: This is a QA site. Straight Up Craft has a free job board where this post may be more appropriate: https://straightupcraft.com/jobs

Answer (score 4):

While the full answer to this probably requires some planning, and a plugin that handles various aspects of the tag management, here are a few components to consider:

You can submit tags from the front-end and, on the server side, they will behave like Craft handles them in the Control Panel. The syntax for your front-end form field is as follows:

```
<select multiple name="fields[fieldHandle][]">
  <option value="13">Tag Name One</option>
  <option value="42">Tag Name Two</option>
  <option value="144">Tag Name Three</option>
</select>
```

For a more friendly UI, there are a handful of javascript libraries that could help on the front-end. I believe the one that Craft uses in the Control Panel is [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) and it could be setup to be used on the front-end as well.

To handle the pre-processing of tag behavior before an Entry is saved, your plugin may need to use the [entries.onBeforeSaveEntry Event](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onBeforeSaveEntry).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One of the challenges is that you can submit tags from the front-end only when you know the ID. selectize.js is really interesting - I will have a look at that.