# Update User Profile with Plugin

Tags: user-profile, usermodel

I'm trying to create a plugin to create/update users' profile data. I figured out how to create a user but updating... not so much.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
$user->setContent(array('middleName' => "Dave"));
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

From what I understand the "saveUser" method is used for both creating and updating user data. Whenever I run the code I get the following error:

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-en_us' for key 'craft_content_elementId_locale_unq_idx'

If **"saveUser"** is truly used for creating and updating what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is causing your error, but it's recommended to use [setContentFromPost()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#setContentFromPost-detail) or [getContent()->setAttributes()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseModel#setAttribute-detail) so that craft has a chance to prep the field values, as discussed in this answer, [setContent() vs $entry->getContent()->foo](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6788/784), and [What is getContent()?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4487/784).

```
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
$user->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
    'middleName' => "Dave",
));
craft()->users->saveUser($user);
```

Although with that error it's possible that something else is going on in your plugin.