# How do I programmatically set a Users company field?

Tags: users

I'm currently able to add a user with the following code (from [the Docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UsersService#saveUser-detail)):

```
$user = new UserModel();
$user->username  = 'tommy';
$user->firstName = 'Tom';
$user->lastName  = 'Foolery';
$user->email     = 'tom@thefoolery.com';

$success = craft()->users->saveUser($user);

if (!$success)
{
    Craft::log('Couldn’t save the user "'.$user->username.'"', LogLevel::Error);
}
```

How can I also set the Profile Company name??

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
$user->company = 'ACME';

$user->setContent([ 'fields' => ['company' => 'ACME'] ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Close! You should be using [setContentFromPost()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#setContentFromPost-detail) for this.  See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6788/57) and [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust) for more info.

You code would look like:

```
$user = new UserModel();
$user->username  = 'tommy';
$user->firstName = 'Tom';
$user->lastName  = 'Foolery';
$user->email     = 'tom@thefoolery.com';
$user->setContentFromPost(array('company' => 'ACME'));

$success = craft()->users->saveUser($user);

if (!$success)
{
    Craft::log('Couldn’t save the user "'.$user->username.'"', LogLevel::Error);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm @brad-bell, that doesn't seem to work... I'm still seeing a blank Company field in the CP. See here: http://bit.ly/1HO5YJO

Comment: Probably a validation error, then?  What does `$user->validate()` return?