# How to save a global set’s content?

Tags: plugin-development, globals, saving

I’m trying to set data within a global set. I’ve tried the following without success:

```
$globalSetHandle = 'settings';
$globalSet = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle($globalSetHandle);

$globalSet->fieldHandle = 'value';

craft()->globals->saveContent(GlobalSetModel $globalSet);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `setContentFromPost`, as mentioned in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4487/110) from Brandon.

```
$content = array(
    'fieldHandle' => 'value',
);

$globalSet->setContentFromPost($content);
craft()->globals->saveContent($globalSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a front-end form:

```
<form method="post">
  {{ getCsrfInput() }}
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="globals/saveContent">
  <input type="hidden" name="setId" value="123"> 
  <input type="text" name="fields[fieldname]" value="{{globalsetslug.fieldname}}">
  <input type="text" name="fields[anotherfieldname]" value="{{globalsetslug.anotherfieldname}}">
  <input type="submit" value="Save globals" />
</form>
```

Of course you need to replace `123` by your globals set id and `globalsetslug` by your globals set slug. You are not required to include all globals set fields in your form, Craft will save only those inside the form.

I know it's an old post, but perhaps this will help others!