# onBeforeSaveEntry listener to add/modify data of some fields

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm trying to build my first, very simple, one file plugin.  I'm having difficulty with a basic task and I can't find any documentation to help me out. Keep in mind that there is no validation whatsoever, I'm just trying to get it to work first.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event)
    {
        $entry = $event->params['entry'];
        $section = craft()->sections->getSectionById($entry['sectionId']);
        if ($section['handle'] == 'institutions')
        {
            $full_address = urlencode(rtrim($entry['adresse'].','.$entry['ville'].','.$entry['province'].','.$entry['codePostal']));
            $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$full_address}&sensor=false&region=ca&key=AIzaSyDhPYj9UwwUYNZYSz9Fo-j75gCJKWVdFeY"));
            $entry->setRawPostContent('latitude' ,$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
            $entry->setRawPostContent('longitude', $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
        }
    });
}
```

I have a listener on entries.onBeforeSaveEntry and it works well.  I check if the section handle is what I need and then I look into the entry data to grab the address fields and query Google map.  All of that is working like a charm.

I can't figure out how to put the data back into the entry for the lat and long filed that exists in my entry type.

```
$entry['latitude'] = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
```

That gives me an error saying latitude is not defined, which is false because I can output the value from it.

Also tried:

```
$entry->setRawPostContent('latitude' ,$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat);
```

Any idea?  I can't find any documentation or google search that can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Brandon's post on this here:
[What is getContent() / the ContentModel, and how do I use it to get and set custom field values?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust/4487#4487)

Basically when you're setting new custom field values, you should use [`setContentFromPost`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#setContentFromPost-detail)

```
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'latitude' => $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat,
);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was close enough with the setRawPostContent().  I should've kept digging.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the recommended way to do this, but this works:

```
$entry->getContent()->myField = 'myValue';
```

So in your case probably this:

```
$entry->getContent()->latitude = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
```