# Why does field value get updated on $element->getContent()->fieldHandle but not when accessed directly $element->fieldHandle?

Tags: custom-fieldtype, entrymodel, contentmodel

I am trying to update a custom field on an EntryModel.  I'm having half success, and I don't understand why. I've looked at other posts [such as this one by Brandon](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4487/115) which discuss how to assign these values and I'm still not having any luck.

The EntryModel I'm trying to update is available in my field type in the `onAfterElementSave` method via `$this->element`.  The handle for the field I want to be updating the value of is available via `$this->model->handle`.

I have tried using `setContentFromPost()`, `setContent()`, `getContent()->setAttributes()` and they all seem to return the same results.

```
$fieldHandle = $this->model->handle;

$this->element->setContentFromPost(array(
    $fieldHandle => 'changedValue'
));

// Accessing the value via getContent returns the update value 'changedValue'
$changedValue = $this->element->getContent()->fieldHandle;

// Accessing the value directly returns the 'originalValue'
$originalValue = $this->element->fieldHandle;
```

Why am I able to successfully update the value for the `getContent()` method but not when I access it directly on the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`setContentFromPost()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ContentModel) performs an operation on the attached *[ContentModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ContentModel)*, not on the element model itself.

When you initialize a *BaseElementModel*, its content attributes are set *from* the associated *ContentModel*. ("Content attributes" means attributes from custom field data, a.k.a. the stuff you'll typically find in the `craft_content` DB table for a given element instance.)

However, later updating the properties of the content model does not immediately ripple into changing the attributes of the element model: You'll need to re-save the element after you do a `setContentFromPost()`, and *then* its magic attributes will reflect your newly set values.

When you `setContentFromPost()`, you're changing the data that will ultimately gets passed into each FieldType's [`prepValueFromPost()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#getContentFromPost-detail) method. If you need to do additional processing later (after each FieldType has done its thing) — such as saving records in an third-party table during `onAfterElementSave` — your service can use `getContent()` to or [`getContentFromPost()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#getContentFromPost-detail) to grab the values it needs, depending on whether you want to access the raw POST data the user submitted, or the values that got returned from each FieldType's `prepValue()` method.