# How to get all (prepped) field values from an entry, indexed by field handle

Tags: plugin-development, field, entries-field, entrymodel

Getting field values, properly prepped, is covered here: [What is getContent() / the ContentModel, and how do I use it to get and set custom field values?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust)

Answer (score 2):

I kept thinking this was in the Craft core.
Wasn't, so I made my own: https://gist.github.com/timkelty/933efd23264d79d91b7a

Has come in useful in plugin dev and some templating.