# Accessing custom fields from User Model

Tags: plugin-development, users, entries-field, usermodel

I have a User entries field called 'company'.
I'm writing a bespoke plugin to manage users in the front-end and was wondering how I can access the content of this field in my plugin via the user model?

Any thoughts as struggling a wee bit here!

Comment: This question will no doubt put you on the right track:
http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust

Comment: Thanks @LukePearce - saw that post and have tried to access via `$user` rather than `$entry` but with no success. Not sure if this is because am referencing an Entry field but proving difficult to see how to access contents.

Answer (score 3):

Response via Slack from Brandon Kelly:

> Accessing custom field values from PHP is the same as in Twig - once you have the UserModel it's just `$user->myCustomFieldHandle`
>   or `$user->myEntriesField->first()`, etc.

Managed to get via following: `$user->company->first()->title`