# How to set a field of an asset from within a plugin

Tags: assets, assetfilemodel

I am using the following code to save an asset that has been downloaded to the storage/runtime/temp directory from an external API

```
$response = craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath(
    $tempPath,
    $photo['FileName'],
    $folderId,
    AssetConflictResolution::Replace
);

// if the response is a success, get the file id
if ($response && $response->isSuccess()) {
    $fileIds[] = $response->getDataItem('fileId');
}
```

In this example `$photo[]` array is the response from the api with all photo information. What I need to do is also save $photo['PhotoId'] to a field I have setup on the photo asset source in Craft.

I can't however find an example of how to achieve this. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To save a custom field value on an Asset, you'll first need to pull the actual AssetFileModel, set the custom attribute on the Asset's [ContentModel](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust), and finally re-save the Asset.

The following example assumes you've set a field `photoId` on your asset source:

```
$fileId = $response->getDataItem('fileId');
$asset = craft()->assets->getFileById($fileId);
$asset->getContent()->setAttribute('photoId', $photo['PhotoId']);
$success = craft()->assets->storeFile($asset);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks!