# Write into Sprout Forms from another plugin

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'd like to be able to create a Sprout Forms entry from another plugin I'm working on. Is this possible?

I had a bit of a look at the **SproutForms_EntriesController->actionSaveEntry()** action but it's kind of all bundled up.

This other plugin is a self contained booking system that I don't want to use an actual Sprout Forms form for - but to keep it consistent for the client I'd like to write (for reference) these entries into a pre-existing form I've set up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When leveraging another plugin programmatically, you will typically want to use the service layer. In your case, the `SproutForms_EntriesService.php` is where the `saveEntry` action gets processed. The `saveEntry` service method expects a `SproutForms_EntryModel`:

```
craft()->sproutForms->saveEntry($entry);
```

Here is a longer example:

```
// Create a new instance of a SproutForms_EntryModel
$entry = new SproutForms_EntryModel();

// Set some SproutForms_EntryModel attributes
$entry->formId    = 4051;
$entry->ipAddress = '127.0.0.1';
$entry->userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36';

// Set the custom fields
$entry->setContentFromPost(array(
    'fullName' => 'Test Name',
    'message' => 'Test message'
));

// Save the entry
craft()->sproutForms_entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Sprout Forms should dynamically set the title value for you, based on the value you have in the `Advanced->Title Format` setting.

In the case it doesn't seem to work, a quick way to see if there are any errors is to kill your script after you tried to save the entry and view the full list of errors (or use a more advanced [PHP debugging workflow](https://straightupcraft.com/events/troubleshooting-and-debugging-errors-in-php) with a tool like XDebug):

```
Craft::dd($entry->getErrors());
```

See the answer from Brandon Kelly on this post for more information on how to [set custom fields on an Element](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/what-is-getcontent-the-contentmodel-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-get-and-set-cust).

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer Ben :) fantastic. I'll give it a try and mark it as correct then.